# Старый добрый DIR 320

Tags: маршрутизатор, d-link

Возникла интересная ситуация, на DIR-320 можно войти по двум адресам, 192.168.1.1 и 192.168.2.1, хотя в настройках маршрутизатора прописан адрес 192.168.2.1 и никаких дополнительных маршрутов и редиректов нет (или мне так кажется) так в чём же дело!?

Comment: Ох, жалко я свой DIR-320 прошил dd-wrt, так что нет возможности посмотреть, как оно там работает…

Comment: Да о тож...

Comment: 192.168.2.1 пингуется? И мак соответствует маку DIR=320?

Comment: В сети других устройств и нет! :) а как с компа увидеть MAC маршрутизатора?

Comment: arp -a (это под виндой)

Comment: Мне тут подсказывают, что нет ничего страшного в том, что у устройства на одном интерфейсе два адреса. Вот.

Comment: Поставил новую прошивку dd-wrt, прикольная штука, открытая линуха :)
Я в ней конечно не великий спец, но зато действительно всё можно посмотреть и отконфигурировать (через виртуальную консоль)

Comment: Согласен! Ещё почитаю, но линукс буду изучать в любом случае (действительно сила)! Всем спасибо!

Comment: И подобные сообщения уместнее было бы оформлять в виде комментариев, в не ответами на собственный вопрос……

Comment: ОК!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Иметь два адреса на одном интерфейсе — вполне нормально.

Если есть доступ внутрь маршрутизатора (Вы тут писали, что прошили его dd-wrt, значит, есть), сделайте на нём ifconfig и посмотрите, чего пишут. Могу предположить, что там будут интерфейсы br0 и br0:0.

Собственно, фича называется ip-alias; почитать можно, например, [тут](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/HOWTO/mini/IP-Alias/index.html).